# C, Inserting a string in a string as a replacement

Tags: c

I program in C and I want to write a function which takes two string and a specific location (start & end) and replaces the characters from the start to the end in the first string with the second string. So the declaring would be something like this: `void replace(char str1[], char str2[], int from, int to);`.

The reason why it's a bit of a problem is because Sometimes the string you want to insert is bigger than the location (from - to) and sometimes is smaller so it doesn't always fit perfect. I thought about the conditions such as `if(strlen(str2) > to-from)` and `else if(strlen(str2) < to-from)` or the formal regular loop which will be by the else (because it's the only option left...).

Do you have any idea what should the loop contain ?

EDIT:
I've got it but one thing's not working. if the string I want to insert into the first one is smaller than the possible between from and to (means I need to supposedly erase the  characters bothering) then it is not working.
The statement which is activated when the string I want to insert is smaller than the possible space is this:

```
    if(strlen(str2) < to-from+1)
{
    location = from+strlen(str2)+1;
    j = 0;
    for (i = from ; i < to && j < strlen(str2) ; i++)
    {
        str1[i] = str2[j];
        j++;
    }
    for(i = location ; i <= to ; i++)
    {
        for(j = i ; j <= strlen(str1) ; j++)
        {
            str1[j] = str1[j+1];
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please format your code properly.

Answer (score 0):

As you properly identified, `str2` may not fit into the space allocated for `str1`.

Since the function prototype you provided does not return a new string, or otherwise permit the input buffer to be reassigned, I don't think what you want is possible in all cases.

If you can, I think you should change the prototype to:

```
char* replace(char* str1, char* str2, int from, int to);
```

By changing the return value, you can return a new buffer, that the caller must free, that will have the resulting output string.

Comment: Thank you for your answer but I know it will be enough because str2 is a string I choose to enter so it will always be in a fit size.